# I have a program on eclipse and exported it as a runnable JAR file, how do I run it on a double click?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAverager {

/**
 * Averages Inputted Numbers
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num1;
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    //int[] numArray = new int[count];
    String input;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {   
        if (count == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the first number you wish to average.");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        count++;

        System.out.println("Please enter your next number or 'calculate' to find the average.");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

            try 
            {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                total = total + num1;
                //numArray[count]=num1;  
            }

                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                        System.out.println("You entered " + count + " numbers.");
                        System.out.println("The average is " + (float)total/count);
                        //System.out.println(numArray[count]);
                        input = "calculate";
                }


    } while (input!= "calculate");

    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

There's my program if that helps,

The manifest says the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: NumberAverager
```

It's just a short program to try to do this, but I don't know what else I have to do to make it work, I'm not sure how to run it from the command line to try it that way, and upon double clicking it the mouse loads for a second and nothing happens

thanks

I'm very new to java, only a beginning semester under my belt, so I need very detailed explanations on how to do this, thanks again

Comment: you can make a .bat file and run this jar

Comment: create shorcut with command 'java -jar path_to_jar'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run exported .jar from Eclipse with double click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414257/how-do-you-run-exported-jar-from-eclipse-with-double-click)

Answer (score 0):

You need a UI for it to display something when you double click. Otherwise it will run the code but its not gonna display anything.

[Here is a tutorial on making a GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you show me what specifically code wise I should add to do this?

Comment: Look at the tutorial. There is a Hello World example

Comment: Thanks looking at it now, so do you think it runs, but just that nothing shows up because there is no GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Use `java -jar` to execute your jar file in command prompt.

```
java -jar C:/path/to/jar/your_jar_file.jar
```

Comment: I type it in just like that in the cmd line?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you enter the full path to your jar file or go to the directory where the jar file exists before executing the command.

Comment: where do I enter the path of the file?

Comment: `java -jar C:/path/to/jar/your_jar_file.jar`

Comment: It said Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\Ben

Comment: Make sure you enclose the path with double quotes if it contains space. `java -jar "C:/path/to/jar/your_jar_file.jar"`

Comment: Okay, so that works and it executes from the cmd line, how do I make it work now by just double clicking it?

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar <PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR_FILE>
```

and make sure java is there in $PATH

Comment: I typed in java -jar C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\NumberAverager.jar
What do you mean make sure java is there?

Comment: on your console, type java --version. It should give an output specifying the java version. If not, make sure jdk is installed properly

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by type it on my console, I'm sorry, do you mean cmd line?

Comment: It says:
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.7.0_10-b18>
Java HotSpot<TM> 64-Bit Server VM <build 23.6-b04, mixed mode>

Comment: the program runs from the cmd prompt I just don't know how to make it run by double clicking it

Comment: Eclipse has an option to package required libraries into the runnable jar. File -> Export... Choose runnable jar and click next. The runnable jar export window has a radio button where you can choose to package the required libraries into the jar.

Comment: The double click thing should work i think. If you are on Windows, then Right Click on the jar itself, go to Open With.. and make sure the selected program is called something like Java(TM) Platform SE Binary. If someting goes wrong open the Java console and paste the error for us to help (go to Java Control Panel, in Control Panel on Windows, Advanced tab, Java console and check Show console).

Comment: Nothing happens when I double click the program, I don't know why, is it because there is no GUI stuff, someone else on here said that?